# SPI interfaces on microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller, serial, spi, io

My question is for microcontrollers in general.  Can SPI be implemented with any 3 different I/O pins granted one is a clock signal?  Is there anything special with certain pins that a datasheet specifies as a master-in, slave-out or slave-select?  Anything special referring to anything unique about the hardware at that pin as opposed to a general I/O pin.

Comment: Bit banging SPI is a pretty common thing to do.

Comment: ..unless the MCU is the slave. Then you ususally have to use the hardware SPI unit to meet the timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the other answers have suggested using bit-banging to solve the problem of assigning an SPI peripheral to any arbitrary pins.  The problem with this is speed; some SPI peripherals can run with a clock speed of 40 MHz or higher, and there is no way to do bit banging with firmware at the rate.

An alternative is to use a hardware architecture that provides periperhal pins to be assigned to any arbitrary pin.  One such microcontroller that does this is the 8051 family from Silicon Labs.  It uses an I/O *crossbar switch* to allow peripherals to be assigned to just about any port pin, as shown below:

[image]

So for example, SCK can assigned to any pin from P0-0 to P3-0, MISO from P0-1 to P3-1 and so on.

The PIC24F family from Microchip also allows for just about any peripheral to be mapped to any number of I/O pins on the microcontroller, using a feature called Peripheral Pin Select.  This is available for peripherals like the UARTs and SPI modules, but not for those that require special hardware like I2C and USB.

The picture below shows a block diagram of the circuitry for a typical I/O pin, with a multiplexer at the top for selecting the output of one of various peripherals to the output pin, and at the bottom, another multiplexer selecting one of several input pins to the input of a peripheral.

The 16-bit PIC24F series can have up to four SPI ports, with any mapped to the 39 remappable pins on a 100-pin microcontroller.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth response.  I learned something new :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can [bit-bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_banging) it. It typically won't be as fast as if there is dedicated hardware.

Don't forget the chip select (so **four** pins for bidirectional communication). Usually you need a chip select for it to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. All outputs are normal push-pull outputs, and all inputs are normal floating inputs. Bang away.

Comment: Might you know of a guide to help with the banging?  I remember a peer while I was a student who was trying to bit-bang spi without him knowing it was SPI.  I couldn't really explain the method to him back then.

Comment: I just define it as "SPI is whatever the SPI timing diagram in the datasheet says it is".

Comment: You just need to be careful about the needs of the slave.  Sometimes it wants the data to be valid on the rising clock edge, and sometimes the falling.

Comment: That's why I pulse the clock rather than just flipping it while the data is valid. It's slightly less compact than switching between data and clock each time, but it handles 2 of the 4 SPI modes (and inverting the clock handles the other two).